# Juli tomcat 7 logging.properties

Tags: file, tomcat, handlers, tomcat-juli

I have a jar that contains a CustomLoginModule to perform JAAS Autherization. This jar is located in `${CATALINA_BASE}/lib` . I have an `org.apache.juli.logging.Log` object that performs logging in the module on different levels. I would like to have a log file e.g. `jaas.log` where the module's logs be written instead of having them in the `Catalina.out` or `catalina.log`. Here's my `logging.properties` file, with this configuration I am able to create the `jaas.log` but it stays empty and all log goes to `Catalina.out` and `catalina.log` can anybody help with this? Thank you very much.

`logging.properties` file:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,          
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,   
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-
manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
#, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,   
5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
#.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,    
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, 5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.


5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix =jaas-auth.


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers =    
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].   
[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].  
[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-mana 
ger].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-  
manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler


com.mymodule.apps.orchestration.CustomLdapLoginModule.level = ALL
com.mymodule.apps.CustomLdapLoginModule.handlers =     
5jaasauth.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: How do you actually obtain and invoke the logger? Did you spell the name of the class `CustomLdapLoginModule` correctly?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I copy-pasted it exactly from my code with its package.